# Transfer lots of files via P2P?

Tags: file-transfer, p2p

I need to transfer about 10Gb of files (really small ones) between my two remote computers. 
I`ve tried creating a torrent and using soulseek with no luck or crazy slow transfers (ports seem to be open). Both computers are on the same ISP with really good connection, so using third-party servers in theory should be ineffective.
Are there simple ways to do this, preferably without zipping?
Using WindowsXP and Windows7.

Comment: have you tried ftp?

Comment: Setting up FTP server? No, i don`t know how to do it, and i`m afraid, it will be slowish with 22.000 files... Ahh, and installing it requires to insert a Windows XP cd, so won't try it for few days...

Comment: see:  http://filezilla-project.org/

Comment: Woohoo, it works perfectly! If you post filezilla server as an answer, I can just plain accept it. However, setup and connection is more than two-clicks, so, not as user-friendly as it could be.

Comment: @JustinasDūdėnas: You do realize that Filezilla is ftp, right?

Comment: @martineau if I managed to setup filezilla ftp server, you could guess, yess :) Just previously I didn`t know alternatives to windows native ftp server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the freely available [filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org) program to do this.  Both client and server programs are free and make setting up FTP almost 2-click easy.         ;-)

hth